# cost header missing for delta query on group

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have the following code to run delta query on AAD group (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-groups):

```
var response = await _graphClient
                   .Groups
                   .Delta()
                   .Request()
                   .Filter($"id  eq '{groupId}'")                   
                   .GetAsync();

var cost = response.AdditionalData["responseHeaders"].GetValues("x-ms-resource-unit").FirstOrDefault();
```

I see that x-ms-resource-unit header missing in the response. Is there a different header to determine the cost of delta api?

Answer (score 0):

In that case the resource unit cost is 1. When the unit cost for the request is 1 then header `x-ms-resource-unit` is not included in the response headers.